# migrate command error : Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver on sql server

Tags: laravel, sql-server-2012, xampp

I have just installed `xampp version 3.2.4`, `Sql Server 2012`, `windows server 2012` `R2`, `php version 7.3.6` and use `laravel as framework` and I am receiving a

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * fr om sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

I check in my `phpinfo() - detected pdo_sqlsrv,`
and if i `try make connection to sql server`, no problem `"Connection established".`

```html
<?php
$serverName = "VPS712345"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"newautocheck", "UID"=>"laravelxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

but if I try to migrate to the database, my project still command error

```html
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * fr
om sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\testdulu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\C
onnection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll
 format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make th
is exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa
se's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\testdulu\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO
Connection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\testdulu\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO
Connection.php:27

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

can help me, how to migrate this project

Comment: Side note: it's best not to post passwords, server names etc. This allows others to access your server as well.

Comment: Could you show us the migration code itself?

Comment: did you put DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv in your .env file?

Comment: php artisan migrate   

and command error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * fr
om sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

Comment: @Kiwi yes my .env 
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=xxx
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=newautocheck
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx

and in my database.php 

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),

Comment: is `DATABASE_URL` unset? this is important because if it is set, laravel ignores all the other ones

Comment: @Kiwi
$DATABASE_URL = parse_url(env('DATABASE_URL', "sqlsrv://myusername:mypassword@myhost/forge"));

but still can not migrate

Comment: still can't,, please help me